# PHP Mysql - Generate encoded unique integer from two integers and decode it

Tags: php, mysql, decode, encode, unique-id

I need to generate encoded unique id from userId, subjectId and decode it. Encoded number should not get duplicate and length must be <=12 and it should be non negative integers only. userId and subjectId are from database and its value, length varies.

I have used base_convert function and converting decimal number to octal.

```
/* Encode function - Converting from decimal to octal 
   $decNum = $usreId.'-'.$subjectId;
*/

function convertDecimalToOctal($decNum){
    $decToOctalNum ='';
    $hyphenPos ='';
    $decToOctal ='';

    $hyphenPos = !($tmp = strpos($decNum, '-')) ? 0 : $tmp; // Get Hyphen Position from string
    $decNum = str_replace('-', '', $decNum); //Replace '-' with '' and get number without '-'

    $decToOctal  = base_convert($decNum,10,8); // Convert from Decimal to Octal

    $decToOctalNum = ($hyphenPos . $decToOctal); // Append the hyphen position to converted octal number

    return $decToOctalNum;
}

/* Decode Function - Converting from octal to decimal */
function convertOctalToDecimal($octNum){
    $getHyphenPos ='';
    $octalToDec ='';
    $octalToDecNum ='';

    $getHyphenPos = substr($octNum, 0, 1); // get hyphen position(digit) from the octal number
    $octNum = substr($octNum, 1); // trim hyphen position off the octal number

    $octalToDec = base_convert($octNum,8,10); // Convert from Octal to Decimal
    $octalToDecNum = substr($octalToDec, 0, $getHyphenPos) . '-' . substr($octalToDec, $getHyphenPos); // Put the hyphen in the converted decimal number

    return $octalToDecNum;
}
```

*As per php.net, base_convert() may lose precision on large numbers due to properties related to the internal "double" or "float" type used.*

How we can make sure this will generate unique numbers for any combination of userId and subjectId? How we can handle the large numbers converting to float type?

We don't want to check in the database for duplicate values. It will take long time to check in database.

Thanks.

Comment: Easiest way to ensure you will not have duplicates is to covert both IDs to string type, join them and then simply cast them to int or bigint or whatever suits your needs. I don't see the need to use hyphens or base conversion. Eg.  userId=12345 subjectId = 12345 becomes new ID=1234512345 so if your previous IDs are unique the new ones will be as well.

Comment: Thank you. But generated uniqueId should not display the userId and subjectId in it. So we are encoding it. User should not be able to see the userId and subjectId.